# Why doesn't strptime() accept my input string?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I'm trying to get the start day of the week, given the year, week number, and start day number.

I have tried to accomplish this by using datetime.strptime() function in ironpython. However, it's not working so far.

```
week_format = "2019-26-1"
startDay = datetime.strptime(week_format, '%Y-%U-%w')
```

Here I'm providing 26 for the week number, I want the week to start from Sunday.

The above code is not working and showing the following error:

```
SystemError: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: maybe just a typo when writing this question, but there is a missing closing ' in the startDay formula

Comment: Thank you, yes that was a typo, fixed now :)

Comment: Which Python and OS are you using? The code works for me with Python 3.5.4 on Windows.

Comment: Yes the code works fine in Python even for me. However, I want to use it in ironpython inside Spotfire, it's not working in ironpython